# How can I delete a print job that is holding up the queue and monitor it?

Tags: printing

I've installed a new printer on a Windows Server 2003 member server. The printer is shared and is assigned the correct permissions. One day when the printer stopped working, I opened the print queue and notice that the first print job in the list says its printing. Unfortunately the print device was NOT printing. So all in all, what would I need to do to delete the print job that is holding up the queue? And to minimize these sorts of problems in the future, I would like to add two more printers to the machine in a print pool configuration. What would the requirements and steps need to be to be able to configure the printer pool?
Finally, how can I monitor the print queue to see how much print activity is happening on the server? All help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power Off your Printer, then Right Click on Print Job and Delete.